# How to import python file from multiple urls

Tags: python, url, import

I'm trying to import an python file from an url. But the only problem i have, i is that if the network is down, my aplication will crash. It is possible if one url is down i can switch to an new url?

My code:

```
def import_py_from_url(self, URL):
    import urllib
    exec urllib.urlopen(URL).read() in globals()

self.import_py_from_url("http://exemple.com/python.py")
```

The error i'm getting:

LoginWindow.__LoadScript.BindObject - :[Errno socket error] [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For multiple urls, here is a simple solution:

```
def import_py_from_urls(self, URLS):
    import urllib

    for url in URLS:
        try:
            exec urllib.urlopen(url).read() in globals()
            break
        except Exception as e:
            # logger a warning message
            continue
    else:
        # all url failed.

self.import_py_from_urls(["http://exemple.com/python.py", "http://another.com/python.py"])
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe a `try:` and `except:`statement could help. Something like this

```
def import_py_from_url(self, URL): # Maybe also add an `URL2` for the alternative
    import urllib
    try:
        exec urllib.urlopen(URL).read() in globals()
    except:
        # <<< add code for your alternative url >>>

self.import_py_from_url("http://exemple.com/python.py")
```

At `self.import_py_from_url` you can add the second url directly. This would give you:

```
def import_py_from_url(self, URL, URL2): 
    import urllib
    try:
        exec urllib.urlopen(URL).read() in globals()
    except:
        exec urllib.urlopen(URL2).read() in globals()

self.import_py_from_url("http://exemple.com/python.py", "http://example-location2.com/python.py")
```